# A riddle of how it is being

Tags: riddle, word

**I'm looking for a nine-letter word.**

---

*It's not easy being
 because it makes me feel very lonely.

People don't even believe being
 is a real thing.
They say being
 is just real in stories.
 In this riddle, I am just being
 (as I am), my true self you know.
Don't want to pretend like I'm like everybody else, when I'm not.
 I'm simply being
 and there's nothing you or I can do to change the fact that being
 makes me feel that I don't even exist.*

---

**What Am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a riddle of how it is being

> **invisible!** (You can imagine the word "invisible" after each "being" in the riddle.)

It's not easy being
because it makes me feel very lonely.

> Being "invisible" (going unnoticed by others) usually does make one feel lonely. Actually being invisible would also probably make one feel lonely for the same reasons.

People don't even believe being
is a real thing.
They say being
is just real in stories.

> Most people think that being invisible is not a real thing. But if one was invisible, it would be extremely hard to convince others of your existence.

In this riddle, I am just being
(as I am), my true self you know.

> Maybe the author of this puzzle is actually invisible!?

Don't want to pretend like I'm like everybody else, when I'm not.
I'm simply being
and there's nothing you or I can do to change the fact that being
makes me feel that I don't even exist.

> The author's invisibility causes the realization of being very different from others, and no one can change that emotional reaction.

Comment: That's the answer! Well done. However, rot13(va guvf evqqyr V npghnyyl **nz** vaivfvoyr. Na vaivfvoyr crefba rkcynvavat ubj vg vf orvat vaivfvoyr ol orvat uvf *gehr frys* ol **abg** rira jevgvat gur jbeq vaivfvoyr. Gung'f jul V raqrq rnpu yvar nsgre "orvat" gur jnl V qvq. Nsgre rnpu "orvat" gur jbeq "vaivfvoyr" pna ercynpr gur rzcgl fcnpr naq pbzcyrgr gur fragrapr. Fb V qvqa'g unir va zvaq nal ersreraprf gb gur erny jbeyq fhpu nf rtb, pbafgehpg bs gur zvaq rgp. V'z fvzcyl na vaivfvoyr crefba gryyvat ubj vg vf gb or vaivfvoyr jvgubhg jevgvat gur jbeq vaivfvoyr.)

Comment: @Prim3numbah I got the part about the answer coming after the word being, although I didn't point it out, but I didn't know you meant it literally, til reading the comment. I will update the answer

Comment: Kudos for including the figurative way of being “invisible “ for the second spoiler!